# What settings should I have for a VNC user?

Tags: vnc

I'm trying to set up a VNC server as per the directions in the following guide:
http://help.godaddy.com/article/6012?locale=en#access

**Some background**:

The first problem I ran into was that there was no `~/.vnc/xstartup` file. I solved that issue by running the `vncstartup` as per these instructions:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9708808&postcount=8

The next problem I ran into was that I could no longer start or stop the service with `/sbin/service vncserver start`. I was receiving the error:

```
Starting VNC server: 2:username [FAILED]
```

The solution that I found was that I was supposed to run `vncstartup :2` while logged in as `username`. This is the link with that info:
http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/applications/125293-vnc-server-failed-start.html

I've now logged into `username` and attempted to run `vncserver :2` but it is giving me this error:

```
vncserver: Could not create /var/www/.vnc.
```

I had created `username` as a web admin account that I originally set up to log in with FTP - thus the `/var/www` directory.

**Finally, the question(s)** - should I be creating an account specifically for VNC separate from the FTP log in account? If so, what directory or settings should this user have so that I can run `vncserver :2` and finally log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to prefer running as a separate user from the web server for normal operation.  When using VNC or any kind of GUI, it's going to expect that your home directory is writable.  You'll need to create a user with a writable home directory to run VNC.  Once that's doable, you should be able to start VNC manually or through a service.

Comment: I've decided to abandon VNC for the time being, so I can't test out what you mentioned but I appreciate the answer.